# Prove there is a point where $f''=0$ when f is three times differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a three times differentiable function. Suppose that $f(0)=3,f(3)=6,f(6)=9$. Prove that there exists $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)=0$.

I have concluded that I should use Mean Value Theorem on some finite interval for $f'(x)$ so then I would get $f''(x)=0$ but I am not sure what this exact interval would be. Since $f$ is three times differentiable, I already know that $f'(x)$ exists on the interval but how could I use the three given points to show that there exists a local maximum or minimum?

Comment: I guess you want to find $f''(x_{0})=0$ instead of $f(x_{0})=0$? Your title is not compatible with the content.

Comment: Additionally, $f(x_0)=0$ does not neccesarily exist. Just take a function that constant on $(-\infty, -1)$ and then changes smoothly enough to the line $f(x)=3+x$ on $(-0, \infty)$

Comment: I was mistaken, it was actually $f''(x_0)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have some $\alpha\in(0,3)$ and $\beta\in(3,6)$ such that $1=\dfrac{f(3)-f(0)}{3-0}=f'(\alpha)$ and $1=\dfrac{f(6)-f(3)}{6-3}=f'(\beta)$, so there exists some $\gamma\in(\alpha,\beta)$ such that $f''(\gamma)=0$.